# XML background image in layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, background

This is ridiculous, no error, I already did the same on some other projects and works fine but it still shows nothing...
Someone knows why my background image is fine in the editor (in the Android Studio editor it shows the background image), but when I run the app on my device, it shows the only white background with just my 2 buttons...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ale.mediaspectrumplayer.MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/background">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ID_MediaPlayer_Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:text="@string/main_MediaPlayer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ID_SpectrumView_Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ID_SpectrumView_Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="@string/main_SpectrumView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.25"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Neither with code it works and I dunno why (layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background), and neither with image view and scale fitXY...that's absurd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, if the image you are using to set as background is of high resolution or is heavy, system just avoids loading it to save the memory. In case you want that image in the background of the whole content, you have to set an image  view whose height and width matches that of the parent layout. Then use an image loading library eg : Picasso, Glide etc to efficiently load the high resolution image in that ImageView without burdening the system

Comment: I just resized the image and now it's working...that's weird cause in one of my other project I used an image the same size as this one...well, that works anyway, so thank you :)

Comment: Its not weird actually, you are loading the image as the background for a ConstrainLayout which is not as good in handling images as ImageView. If you try loading original image in the imageview, the chances of getting expected results are higher.

Comment: The imageview didnt work either... but i was saying thats weird cause in my other project I loaded a similar image (i mean, similar size) and it worked...thats why i said "weird"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `android:scaleType` attribute? This can change the position of the background image to cover the screen, sometimes if the image is too small it won't show up. Setting `scaleType` to `center` or `centerCrop` might help.

Here's the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: Neither of them do what I want...scaleType: center just center the image (in imageview) and its not working as background, centerCrop don't fix the image as background, its just bigger than the screen size

Answer (score 0):

try Changing parent layout to RelativeLayout or any other layout.